# How to test a request spec when an API Key is required

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, http-headers

I'm trying to write a request spec for my API, but need to pass the API key. The API Key is passed as a header. In a web from I pass it like this:

`Header: Authorization`

`Value: Token token="MyString"`

In my spec I'm trying this:

```
describe "sessions" do
  before do
    FactoryGirl.create(:api_key)
  end

  it "is authenticated with a token" do
    put "/api/v1/users/#{@user.id}?user_email=#{@user.email}&auth_token=#{@user.authenti‌​cation_token}", {user: {name: "New Name"}}, { 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION' => "Token token=\"MyString\"" }
    response.status.should be(201)
  end
end
```

That doesn't raise an exception, but it also doesn't work. My test just fails with error code `401`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a simple formatting. I had to add some logging to see exactly how the Authorization header was being sent. I just copied that output and replaced the values with my testing values, so the right answer is:

```
it "is authenticated with a token" do
        put "/api/v1/users/#{@user.id}?user_email=#{@user.email}&auth_token=#{@user.authentication_token}", {user: {name: "New Name"}}, { "HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"=>"Token token=\"#{@api_key.access_token}\"" }
        response.status.should be(201)
      end
```

There was another problem that I found while adding logging. I had a before filter that was changing my api_token, so my testing api_token of "secret" was being changed to a real api_token before the call was being sent. Whops. So the moral is that it's worth the time to write the tests.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the headers hash is supposed to be the third argument to `put` (same for `get`, `post`, etc.). In your example, you have it as the second.

From the docs:

```
put(path, parameters = nil, headers_or_env = nil)
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Integration/RequestHelpers.html#method-i-put

Comment: I changed it to: `put "/api/v1/users/#{@user.id}?user_email=#{@user.email}&auth_token=#{@user.authenti‌​cation_token}", {user: {name: "New Name"}}, { 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION' => "Token token='MyString'" }` but am still getting a `401` response in my tests.